# How does the RxJS from operator create a source that emits multiple entries in an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Looking at [this example from the learn RxJS documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/groupby.html):

```
const source = from(people);
```

That creates a source that emits each person.  I added [typing to the source in a Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-from-operator?file=index.ts) and the source can be typed like this:

```
source:Observable<Person>
```

So it looks like the source is an `Observable` of at single person instance.  However it emits multiple instances of `Person`.  How does this work?  In other words, if I just read the `source` type, I would expect that source is an `Observable` that will emit a single person only.

Comment: How what works? The `from`? The `groupBy`?

Comment: In other words, if I just read the `source` type, I would expect that source is an Observable that will emit a single person only.

Comment: Why is that? Would you expect an `Array<Person>` to contain only single person as well?

Comment: The type`Observable<X>` just means that every object the observable emits is an `X`. It doesn't say how many objects are emitted.

Comment: Hmmm ... I think I see what I'm missing now.  So essentially `Observable<Person>` can emit a stream of `Person` instances?

Comment: That's what observables are for yes :)

Comment: OK COOL!!  Got it.  Thanks!